# How to switch the root from controllers without resizing the window in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, root, fxml

(James_D has showed me the solution. I'll just elaborate on how it helped me and what I did at the end of this question. Hopefully others find it useful.)

My wrong initial approach:

There are several FXML files and their controllers in my program. I loaded the FXML files and changed the scenes. It caused the window size to change when it was maximized.

Then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39985521/7778728) answer showed that I should change the root instead.

Current approach and question:

I tried the code given in the answer there and it works flawlessly. First I set a root in the start method and switched to anther root after a time delay. It's just to check. It looks like this:

```
package com;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Launcher extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);

}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    StackPane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/com/Scene2.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setMaximized(true);
    stage.show();

    Timeline timeline2 = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), e2 -> {

        try {
            StackPane root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/com/Scene1.fxml"));
            scene.setRoot(root2);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }));
    timeline2.play();

}

}
```

In my actual program the start method loads an FXML file. Later I click buttons or something on the screen which should change the root. So I'll have to use a similar code in controllers. But to set the root, I need to get the scene. In the start method the scene is already created and available. I can't figure out how to get that in a controller. So I tried creating a new scene in the controller. But it's not working. It doesn't throw exceptions or anything. The program simply doesn't do anything when I press the button. This is the relevent code in the controller.

```
public void changeRoot(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        try {               
            Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/com/Scene2.fxml"));

            // I added the line below.
            Scene scene = new Scene(root2);   

            scene.setRoot(root2);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The solution:

Right then. As you can see from the comment below, I can get the scene by calling getScene() on any node in the current scene. In my example code I have a button on the current screen. A button is a node. So I use it to get the scene. I'll just share the code of the controller class so you know what I mean.

```
package com;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Scene1Controller implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Button button;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {


}

    public void changeRoot(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        try {               
            Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/com/Scene2.fxml"));

            button.getScene().setRoot(root2);     // Here I get the scene using the button and set the root.

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Now there's something you should keep in mind. You have to make sure you give an fx:id for the node in FXML. It should match the given variable name of the node in the controller. For example, in my controller I have a Button. I've named it 'button'. I've also made sure the id for the Button in the FXML file is 'button'. It's very easy to set the fx:id. I used the Gluon Scene Builder. (Sometimes the changes I make there doesn't get updated in Eclipse right away. Refreshing the project makes sure the changes are updated in Eclipse too.)

Comment: Why do you think creating a new scene would help? You can simply call `getScene()` on any node in the current scene (so anything that's injected into the controller) to get a reference to the existing scene.

Comment: @James_D Thank you so much! It works! I actually tried that after searching for and reading another answer. But I hadn't given the control an ID. You mentioning injected made me realize that and fix it. You have no idea how much this help of yours means to me, bro. Thank you so so much. Really. I'll edit my question to detail what mistakes I did and what I should have done. Hopefully others in the future find it useful. Also, if you would be so kind as to post what you said here as an answer, I could accept it.